# How to find the assembly registered in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr

i have an assembly registered in SQL Server:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [CLRFunctions]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM  0x4D5A90000300000...
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

How can i find the path to the this assembly?

Comment: What do you mean by "path" ? The assembly is stored inside SQL Server - in binary form. You can inspect what assemblies are stored in SQL server using `select * from sys.assemblies` - but again: those aren't present as files on a disk or anything - those are stored inside SQL Server's data pages.

Comment: The assembly is in a SQL server somewhere not on a disk in a folder. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @marc_s By path i meant *"path to the assembly dll that contains the functions that SQL can call"*. Turns out i started from a faulty assumption, and proceeded logically to a faulty question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deprecated (as of the release of SQL Server 2005 which introduced SQLCLR) extended stored procedure API / feature (i.e. XPs) did point to external DLLs. This meant that they could get deleted and were not included in backups of the database. With SQLCLR, the assemblies are imported into the database and can be accessed via `sys.assembly_files`. Having the assemblies contained within the database guarantees that they are included in all DB backups (among the other benefits of not magically disappearing or being replaced without your knowledge, etc).

Execute the following to see what assemblies you have loaded, their original paths (only if they were loaded from an external DLL and not from a `VARBINARY` literal / hex bytes), and their full contents/bytes:

```sql
SELECT asm.[name] AS [Assembly], afl.[name] AS [PathOrAltName], afl.[content]
FROM   sys.assembly_files afl
INNER JOIN sys.assemblies asm
        ON asm.[assembly_id] = afl.[assembly_id]
ORDER BY asm.[name];
```

If the assembly was loaded from a `VARBINARY` literal / hex bytes (i.e. `0x4D5A9000...`), then the `[name]` column in `sys.assembly_files` should be the same as the `[name]` column in `sys.assemblies` (which is the name used in the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement).

For more information on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)

Answer (score 5):

It is not an assembly reference in SQL Server, the assembly is actually loaded in the database.  Therefore there isn't a typical "path".

If you're looking for a SQLPS (PowerShell) path then it'd be:

```
SQLSERVER:\SQL\YourServerName\YourInstanceName\Databases\YourDatabaseName\Assemblies\
```

Comment: That explains it then, @marc_s and MickaelEriksson. i would never have imagined, ever, that an assembly is copied into SQL Server itself.