# Is it possible to find out the original path that was used to load the assembly in SQL SERVER CLR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlclr

I am very new to working with Assemblies CLR in SQL Server

I have a database that has many of them
[image]

Is it possible to find out the original path that was used to load the assembly ?

Considering this is the way the assemblies are created I need that "from" path

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY ClassLibrary1 
from 'D:\DotNetTeam\SQLServer\ClassLibrary1.dll'
```

I'm asking this because this assembly : a798b6eb4255719355458f3749073dc1b is not found on the server list and is being reported as unsecure (I know I have to sign it, but for that I need to first find it)

I found this other question but is not what I need.
[How to find the assembly registered in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102754/how-to-find-the-assembly-registered-in-sql-server)

**UPDATE**

Querying the sys.assembly_files table, I notice that the record exists there but not on the left side (Object Explorer: Assemblies), do I need to re-created the assembly ?

```
select * 
from sys.assembly_files
where name like 'a79%'
```

[image]

The solution for this question might also help you solve any of these
errors:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'ASSEMBLY_NAME, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
> or one of its dependencies. An error relating to security occurred.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A)
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'ASSEMBLY_NAME, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
> or one of its dependencies. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80FC80F1

Comment: Removing the [tag:assembly] tag since it is for assembly language.

Comment: Short answer: no. The file is loaded at create time and then the contents are stored in the database. The original location is not recorded, nor is the file used again at any time afterwards. `sys.assembly_files` can at least help you with the name of the file.

Comment: If you want you can export the orignal DLL and the sign / reimport it. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3126/exporting-clr-assemblies-from-sql-server-back-to-dll-files/

Comment: I have updated the question with a query to the sys.assembly_files and a new question

Comment: What is meant by: `_assembly : a798b6eb4255719355458f3749073dc1b is not found on the server list_` and `the file exists there but not on the left side`?

Comment: If you take a look the second image, the left side of the Object Explorer does not show the assembly but is listed in the sys.assembly_files table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but *only* if the assembly was loaded from a DLL on the file system and *not* by supplying the `VARBINARY` literal / hex bytes. When loaded from an external DLL (a method that I strongly recommend *against*, btw), the original path is stored in the `[name]` column in `sys.assembly_files`.

Execute the following to show any potential paths:

```
-- Change this to the assembly name or path to apply filter:
DECLARE @AssemblyName NVARCHAR(260) = '';
    
-- The content can be used to export the DLL:
SELECT asm.[name] AS [Assembly],
       afl.[name] AS [PathOrAltName],
       asm.[permission_set_desc],
       afl.[file_id],
       afl.[content]
FROM   sys.assembly_files afl
INNER JOIN sys.assemblies asm
        ON asm.[assembly_id] = afl.[assembly_id]
WHERE asm.[name] LIKE N'%' + @AssemblyName + N'%'
OR    afl.[name] LIKE N'%' + @AssemblyName + N'%'
ORDER BY asm.[name], afl.[file_id];
```

If the assembly was loaded from a `VARBINARY` literal / hex bytes (i.e. `0x4D5A9000...`), then the `[name]` column in `sys.assembly_files` should be the same as the `[name]` column in `sys.assemblies` (which is the name used in the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement).

---

> Querying the `sys.assembly_files` table, I notice that the record exists there but not on the left side

To be clear, both screen shots in the question clearly show a long list of very poorly (and clearly programmatically) named assemblies. And it is not possible, in any way, for an entry to show up in `sys.assembly_files` (or any of the other assembly-related management views) without it existing in `sys.assemblies`.

ALSO: are you certain that you are in the same database in the query window that you are drilling-down into in Object Explorer?

> they only provided me a database backup

Assemblies physically exist in each DB where `CREATE ASSEMBLY` was executed and show up in `sys.assemblies`, `sys.asssembly_files`, and a few other system catalog views. This is one of many benefits of SQLCLR: the assembly is not external to the DB as is the case with the now deprecated external stored procedure API / feature (i.e. XPs).

> I know I have to sign it...

So then I assume you are restoring a pre-SQL Server 2017 DB into SQL Server 2017 or newer. In this case you do need to sign all unsigned assemblies, *BUT* you do *not* need to export them in order to do this (an extremely common misunderstanding due to Microsoft misunderstanding the issue themselves and hence providing incorrect documentation on this topic). This is rather simple to solve given that you can sign the assembly in-place in order to get past the new "CLR strict security" debacle:

[SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 4: “Trusted Assemblies” – The Disappointment (Msg 10314)](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/28/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-4-trusted-assemblies-the-disappointment/)

Here is a summary of the steps:

1. Create Certificate (using a password) in the DB containing the assembly / assemblies using `CREATE CERTIFICATE ...`
2. Sign the Assembly using `ADD SIGNATURE TO Assembly::[{assembly_name}] ...`
3. Copy the Certificate to `[master]` (but not the Private Key!)
4. Create a Login from the Certificate
5. Grant the signature-based Login the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission
6. You will still need to make sure that each assembly has the correct `PERMISSION_SET` for what it needs to do

Here is the demo script from that article that you can copy and adjust to fit your needs:

[Avoiding "Trusted Assemblies" - Demo](https://pastebin.com/mwi5BidL) (on PasteBin)

---

For more information on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)

**UPDATE (from O.P.):**

The issue was that the name of the assembly was **ComputeHashFuncAssmembly** but the path was the one that contained **a798b6eb4255719355458f3749073dc1b** so an `ALTER ASSEMBLY` was needed. That was also the reason it was not visible on the left side because it was under **ComputeHashFuncAssmembly** and not as the hex code.

[image]

I exported the assembly because the original DLL was not provided to me and I wanted to have it.

These are the steps for signing the assembly

```
USE [yourDatabase];
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE [AssemblyCertificate]
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'aPasswordYouChoose'
WITH SUBJECT = 'Assembly Certificate';

ADD SIGNATURE TO Assembly::[ComputeHashFuncAssmembly]
    BY CERTIFICATE [AssemblyCertificate]
    WITH PASSWORD = 'aPasswordYouChoose';

ALTER ASSEMBLY ComputeHashFuncAssmembly
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;

-- Copy the certificate to the master
BACKUP CERTIFICATE [AssemblyCertificate] TO FILE = 'C:\temp\certificate.cer';

USE [master];
GO

-- DROP certificate [AssemblyCertificate];
CREATE CERTIFICATE [AssemblyCertificate]
FROM FILE ='C:\temp\certificate.cer';

CREATE LOGIN [login_AssemblyCertificate]
FROM CERTIFICATE [AssemblyCertificate];

GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO [login_AssemblyCertificate];
```

Comment: That querie returns nothing for the wanted assembly (WHERE asm.[name] like 'A79%'), but I have updated my question, can you please review it ?

Comment: Hi there. I see the update. Please answer the two questions I posted to the question so that I can better understand how to help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that is the think I dont know how was the Assembly created, they only provided me a database backup and the assembly is showing up in the sys.assembly_files but not in the object explorer on the left, is that normal ?

Comment: I still do not understand what you think is missing on the "left" given that both images in the question clearly show a long list of very poorly (and clearly programmatically) named assemblies. And yes, assemblies physically exist in each DB where `CREATE ASSEMBLY` was executed and shows in `sys.assemblies`, `sys.asssembly_files`, and a few other catalog views. This is one of many benefits of SQLCLR: the assembly is _not_ external to the DB as is the case with the now deprecated external stored procedure API / feature (i.e. XPs).

Comment: let me put it this way then,when an Assembly is CREATED should it be listed on the OBJECT EXPLORER ? (the list if alphabetically ordered in hexadecimal and none of them show the 'A79....' assembly

Comment: So I managed to export the content of the assemly and try to CREATE and got this error Msg 6285, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because the source assembly is, according to MVID, identical to an assembly that is already registered under the name "ComputeHashFuncAssmembly". and yes the assembly is already under that name. will update you when gets solved

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Are you saying that you exported the assembly and then executed `CREATE ASSEMBLY` with it in the same DB without first deleting what was exported? You would need to execute `ALTER ASSEMBLY` in that case. I think there is a naming mismatch somehow. Look at the updated query in my answer as it now allows for filtering on the name in both views. I am curious about the name of it in `sys.assemblies` based on matching it in `sys.assembly_files` (where you clearly see it now). Also, I added instructions re: signing the assembly without needing to export it.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Thanks for accepting :). I think the MVID error is due to it being under a name that you are not expecting (hence why you don't see it listed under the assemblies folder), and trying to recreate it with a new name, yet it's still the same physical assembly (which is not allowed, clearly).

Comment: Solomon I have updated the answer with the steps that I run but I am getting the same error 0x8013150A Do I need to create new question ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez You might just need to set the assembly to have `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`. I updated my query in the answer to include the current setting in the results. Please let me know the current value. Oh, and I linked to the demo script (shows how to copy the certificate without resorting to using a file) as well, though it looks like you did all of the steps correctly (which is why I'm thinking it is hopefully just the `PERMISSION_SET` that is wrong.

Comment: I have actually used PERMISSION_SET = SAFE; because signing an UNSAFE assembly is not possible, I have update my part of the answer to include that.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Interesting. Thanks for mentioning that. I'm guessing that the assembly already being set to `UNSAFE` means that this DB originally had [TRUSTWORTHY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/trustworthy-database-property) enabled, which allows it to bypass real security (i.e. the approach I described in my answer). When restoring or attaching a DB, `TRUSTWORTHY` is automatically set to `OFF`, so it stopped working. If the code executes while set to `SAFE`, then best to keep it as `SAFE`.